# MQL_DLLS_ALLOWED cannot be set

Tags: c#, c++, .net, mql5, metatrader5

I want to know if there is any way to set the property id values of the `ENUM_MQL_INFO_INTEGER` using external program or dll or anything. 
I tried this:

```
int OnInit()
  {
//---
   MQL_DLLS_ALLOWED = 1;
   Print(MQLInfoInteger(MQL_DLLS_ALLOWED));
//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
```

It gave error:

```
'MQL_DLLS_ALLOWED' - l-value required   TestingEnum.mq5 15  4
'1' - cannot convert enum   TestingEnum.mq5 15  22
'=' - l-value required  TestingEnum.mq5 15  21
```

Kindly, let me know what I can do.

Comment: Looks like rather `c++` , not `c#`, and definitely not `vb.net`, as `l-value` is a term from `c++`. Are you sure about language tags?

Comment: @Renat May be but thank you. Can you help me with what I trying to achieve? I will edit.

Comment: Please can anyone help me. I am stuck with the manual work. I am consistently experimenting with the stuff. And for that I need to allow the dll and then disallow it because of security norm that I have to follow.

Comment: On `MQL_DLLS_ALLOWED` doc page ( https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/environment_state/mql5_programm_info ) only usage of it mentioned is by `MQLInfoInteger` function, which cannot change it. So I'd bet `MQL_DLLS_ALLOWED` permission cannot be changed programmatically. Looks like it only could be set before the program start, here https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/runtime/tradepermission on the 2nd screenshot there is a checkbox 'Allow DLL imports'

Comment: @Renat I know manually I can do it. But I want a programmatic way out for that. See I have change my program 100 of times and I need to set and reset the dll permissions for the platform. Thats the reason I do not want to change it manually. Can you image how much tedious it would be to do it manually a 100 time a day? Hence, was looking for some solution if with MQL5 or without it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you with your question directly, mainly because of the reasons discussed in the comments. I believe you can check the value whether DLL is allowed, but you cannot enable/disable it easily. Maybe there is a way with running MT terminal from the command line, with some keys allowing or blocking dll, so you may check. But that means restarting your platform, I am not sure that is convenient.

If I were you, and tired of enabling/disabling dll dozen times, I would introduce a global variable of client terminal, with values 0 or 1 (doubles of course). Then, if it is zero, dlls are not called, and ea does not start (if you check that in `OnInit()`), if it is non-zero value, dll works. A simple script changing this GV can be written and hot keys assigned. In that case, hotkey blocks everything, and allows dll again when needed.
In case you need any help with that - I will edit my code and provide some basic examples.

Comment: Your advise and suggestion is marvelous. But let me share with you. I am in need to changing the  values of `ENUM_MQL_INFO_INTEGER`. And there are many things in there. Allowing dll is one of them. So I guess the perfect solution would be something that will help me change the values of the enum type variable that has been declared. Can you help me?

Comment: `ENUM_MQL_INFO_INTEGER is a classical enum, you cannot reassign enums of course. And MQL5 can only provide results of `MQLInfoInteger()` and no way to sth like MQLSetInteger() or similar function. That is why I suggested the workaround